# Are synthetic empires at disadvantage at land warfare?

Tags: stellaris

The "Synthetic Dawn" DLC added the ability to play as a robot empire and changed many technologies and traits to match the "Synthetic" theme. Has the same been done to the land warfare?

If you look at the [wiki page](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Land_warfare) you will see that all the armies type (clone, genetic warriors, slaves, xenomorphs) are organic in nature, there is only one pure robotic army. On top of that, you can make your organic specie "strong" (or "very strong") giving all your armies +20/+40% damage - [robots have no such traits](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Traits#Advanced_traits). So organic empire can build Gene warriors (which seems to be unavailable to syntetics) that already deals almost twice the regular army damage AND boost it by 40% by making those warriors from "very strong" subspecies.

So, are robotic empires in disadvantage when it comes to land warfare? Can they unlock other, more powerful armies, or maybe can they use the special organic ones?

Comment: Strong and Very Strong are empire modifiers not attachments to armies Not sure what you're asking about default armies, aren't they all the basic assault

Comment: @n_palum http://www.stellariswiki.com/Traits#Positive Strong and very strong are specie traits. You can create sub-specie and use it to build your armies.

Comment: Yes. But you're asking about a "pure robotic army" for the type of army, and then about the civics/species traits. You're comparing different things, it's confusing atm

Comment: Organics can make for example gene warriors with basic 3-6 damage instead of norma 1.75-3.45 . If you make gene wariors from specie that is very strong you will get bonus 40% on top of that. Since robots can't be "very strong" they are at disadvantage here.

Comment: Machines do get advanced armies from tech but the stats aren't on the wiki yet. I'm playing a machine empire game now- I'll try to find the stats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Machine empires with the right technology can produce powerful late-game armies of their own.

Adaptive Combat Algorithms allows machines to produce powerful Battle Frame Armies. Biomechanics allows them to build Mega-Warforms- giant death robots which are on par with Gene Soldiers.

While machines can't add the Extremely Strong trait to their pops for extra damage, they make up for this with near-unbreakable morale and immortal generals. It's hard to say which is better but they are definitely able to compete late-game.